# Excel cell format issue

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am writing data into a excel sheet and I am applying Number format to the range of cells using interop. The code is working fine, when I open the excel sheet the format is applying to the cell but its not working(like I have right click and checked the format of the cell it is Number but cell value is displaying as text).

I have used below code to set format

```
Excel.Range range = objWorksheet.get_Range("B2").EntireColumn;
range.NumberFormat = "0";
```

when I open the excel the cell format is Number but its displaying as text.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "displaying as text"?

Comment: `when I open the excel sheet the format is applying to the cell but its not applying.` What? :)

Comment: I have added image for more understanding of my question

Comment: It's nothing to do with the number format (which is correct) it's to do with how you are populating the cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Excel.Range oRange = objWorksheet.get_Range("A1:C10");
foreach(Excel.Range cell in oRange.Cells)
{
    cell.Formula = cell.Formula
}
```

If I put the above piece of code after my completion of the write process its working fine.

Comment: This does not make sense at all but solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you include how you are writing data?

I'm not sure that this is a vital change, because even if a number is stored as text in Excel, you can still perform mathematical operations on it.

There are many changes that you could make. I will try to outline a few.

You could manually insert a function in the cell to the right and just make it equal to the column with the numbers stored as text multiplied by 1. This would create a column with cells in general format.

If it has to be in VBA, you could also simply include this sub as well at the end of however you are writing the data:

```
Public Sub changetextnumbers()
       Range("A:A").Select 'Change to reflect the column
       With Selection
            Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
                     .Value = .Value
       End With
End Sub
```

There is more that we could do with this, but we would need to see more of how you write data.

Comment: string[,] sheetEntries = ConvertDataTableToArray(pDataTable);
                objWorksheet.get_Range(startRange + ":" + endRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = sheetEntries;